# Is it possible to programmatically change the config_sync_directory path after profile installation?

Tags: configuration, installation-profiles

Installing Drupal 9 using a custom profile installation, I have defined `"config_sync_directory"` in `settings.php` file in `$settings` array to pick up the profile config during installation.

1. During site installation Drupal asks to specify the "config" directory in the settings file
2. In a custom profile I have some default configurations, I want Drupal to read configurations from that directory during installation, the path I specified in the settings file.
3. Now, post-installation I want to specify a separate config sync directory, and do not want to edit the settings.php file, again and again, just wanted to update the sync directory path from a hook in the custom module.

Is it possible to change the path programmatically from a hook?

Comment: You can simply edit settings.php why would you need it to be updated from some hook?

Comment: Please check below for the reason I wanted this but looks like not possible.

Comment: You can update that value any time after installation by just editing settings.php. I don't see any explanation that clarifies why you ain't able to do so. Simply open settings.php in the editor of your choice (maybe clear file permissions first), edit that value, save (and maybe strengthen file permission again). Just ensure you also move the config directory to the new location. That's all.

Comment: @leymannx Actually what I wanted to achieve was 

1. During site installation Drupal asks to specify the "config" directory in the settings file 
2. In a custom profile I have some default configurations, I want Drupal to read configurations from that directory during installation, the path I specified in the settings file.
3. Now, post-installation I want to specify a separate config sync directory, and do not want to edit the settings.php file, again and again, just wanted to update the sync directory path from a hook in the custom module.

Hope I made the requirements clear.

Comment: When you install a profile its config gets read from the profile's config directory regardless of what you configured in settings.php. And it's really important that you add that to your question. Otherwise you won't get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @leymannx That is not the case, during installation it reads config from the config path given in the settings file.

Comment: If that's not working during installation, then something's wrong in your profile. Check other profile's (minimal, standard) config directories on where the config is supposed to be exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules can override the values in configuration objects. As described in [Configuration override system / Providing overrides from modules](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/configuration-override-system#s-providing-overrides-from-modules), a module needs to implement a service tagged *config.factory.override*. The class used for the service needs to implement [`ConfigFactoryOverrideInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21ConfigFactoryOverrideInterface.php/interface/ConfigFactoryOverrideInterface/9.3.x), as the example given in the documentation does.

```yaml
services:
  config_example.overrider:
    class: Drupal\config_example\Config\ConfigExampleOverrides
    tags:
      - {name: config.factory.override, priority: 5}
```

```php
namespace Drupal\config_example\Config;

use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata;
use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryOverrideInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Config\StorageInterface;

/**
 * Example configuration override.
 */
class ConfigExampleOverrides implements ConfigFactoryOverrideInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function loadOverrides($names) {
    $overrides = [];
    if (in_array('system.site', $names)) {
      $overrides['system.site'] = ['name' => 'Overridden site name!'];
    }
    return $overrides;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheSuffix() {
    return 'ConfigExampleOverrider';
  }
  
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheableMetadata($name) {
    return new CacheableMetadata();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function createConfigObject($name, $collection = StorageInterface::DEFAULT_COLLECTION) {
    return NULL;
  }

}
```

Keep in mind that the value in the *settings.php* file always override the module values. For a module to set a configuration value, the *settings.php* file needs not to set it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I am defining the config sync folder path in settings.php which is working properly. Now after that once Drupal is installed successfully I want to update this config sync folder path and it is not a config, it is a Setting.

Comment: There's no hook for overwriting global settings if that's what you mean. There's no need for one, you can just edit settings.php to reflect the desired new value instead of editing a hook in a module file

Comment: Yes, Settings are by design read-only. Only in tests they replace the entire singleton instance. For example [KernelTestBase::setUpFilesystem](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21KernelTests%21KernelTestBase.php/function/KernelTestBase%3A%3AsetUpFilesystem)

Comment: Thanks to all for the clarifications.

Comment: With cli drush config-import --source=SOURCE you can define specific config folders.